# Configure first day of the week for xfce calendar in centos 7

Tags: xfce, calendar

I have centos 7 with xfce.

And I cannot find where is the necessary configuration file located to make Monday as first day of the week.

[image: xfce calendar]

Comment: Change/adjust your locale. https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?t=49010 https://necromuralist.github.io/posts/changing-the-first-day-of-the-week-in-ubuntu-2004/ https://askubuntu.com/questions/197613/monday-as-first-day-in-gnome-shell-instead-of-sunday https://askubuntu.com/questions/6016/how-to-set-monday-as-the-first-day-of-the-week-in-gnome-calendar-applet

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Ideally, add this as an answer rather than a comment ;)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thank for links, I have searched how to change the locale for Centos and found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Artem S. Tashkinov, about links.

I have found solution for centos:
https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-set-up-system-locale-on-centos-7/

And the right command to change the locale for centos is:

```
localectl set-locale LANG=en_GB.utf8
```

And after that it is necessary to restart the OS.