# Configure first day of the week without changing language/locale in Xfce (fedora)

Tags: fedora, xfce, panel

my question is related to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/668477/configure-first-day-of-the-week-for-xfce-calendar-in-centos-7) one.

Is there an easy way to change the first day of the week in XFCE calendar (xfce4-datetime-plugin) WITHOUT changing the language? I want to keep my language setting to English, so changing locale is not an option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. There are locales other than en_US which have Monday as the first day of the week, e.g. `en_DK.UTF-8`, `en_GB.UTF-8` and `en_IE.UTF-8`. Or you could file a feature request. :-)

To figure it out I've used this script:

```bash
for i in `localectl list-locales`; do echo "$i"; LANG=$i cal; done
```

2. Also, you don't have to redefine `LANG`, you can get away with `LC_TIME`.
3. Lastly you can `killall xfce4-panel; LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 xfce4-panel &> /dev/null & disown`